# Can I just delete my git working directory?

Tags: git

I am newish to Git. If I am done with a repo and has pushed everything onto Github and don't want the files locally anymore, can I just delete the working directory through the filesystem? Is there some better way or some kind of "best practice"?

Comment: yeah all you have to do is delete `.git`

Comment: Deleting just the `.git` folder will only remove the git repository locally.  Not all the files that result from that repository locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can delete that folder locally.

But if your intention is to remove the link between local dire and git repo then you can just remove .git folder under your local directory.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: yes. If you've pushed everything to a remote repo, you can delete the local files. If you ever need the local files again, you can just clone them from the remote repository.